# In one directory new files are executable by default

Tags: file, unix, permissions, default, executable

For some reason one of my directories has started producing
executables. By this I mean that new files in that directory are
a+x (but not, for example in the parent directory):

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxrwsr-x  2 me me 45 Dec  5 10:22 ./
drwxrwsr-x 10 me me 13 Dec  5 10:22 ../
$ rm -f test
$ touch test
$ ls -l test
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me 0 Dec  5 10:25 test*
$ cd ..
$ rm -f test
$ touch test
$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 me me 0 Dec  5 10:26 test
```

Also, notice the + at the end of the second permissions line, is it significant?

I know it cannot be a `umask` thing...but it's set at 0002.

How can I turn off this behavior?

---

EDIT:

In response to an answer below I ran the following (in the parent dir):

```
$ touch test
$ getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: me
# group: me
user::rw-
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

Why do I have this mask? Is this the right value for it? How can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

The `+` indicates the presence of one or more ACLs on the entry. `getfacl test` will show you more information. The oddity with the apparent executability of new files may be related to the ACLs in the parent directory, but we'd have to see what they are to know for sure...